# How do Class definitions work in VBA

Tags: vba, class

As i am trying to learn VBA, Classes are blasting me some heavy duty pain!!!

Here is something from one of my VBA books (VBA and Macros Microsoft Excel 2010 - Bill Jelen at page 497) which is absolutely bizzare and peculiar:

1. We open a class module in VBE
2. And we are writing the 4 properties and 1 method of the custom object in the class module `clsEmployee`:

   ```
   'Properites   
   Public EmpName As String             
   Public EmpID As String   
   Public EmpRate As Double         
   Public EmpWeeklyHrs As Double

   'Methods   
   Public Function EmpWeeklyPay() As Double  
       EmpWeeklyPay = EmpRate * EmpWeeklyHrs  
   End Function
   ```
3. The book writes that the custom object is now complete
4. Now the book goes to open a simple module (not a class module) to reference the custom object from another module, so it goes:

   ```
   Dim Employee as clsEmployee

   Set Employee = New clsEmployee
   ```
5. Not it presents all the code block. Really awkward thing here is that the *Dim Employee as clsEmployee* is **outside of the sub procudure! Why?** (So this could be seen as the minor question)

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Dim Employee as clsEmployee 'why is this outside of the code block?

   Sub EmpPay()
       Set Employee = New clsEmployee

       With Employee
           .EmpName = "Tracy Syrstad"
           .EmpID = "1651"
           .EmpRage = 25
           .EmpWeeklyHrs = 40

           MsgBox .EmpName & " earns $" & .EmpWeeklyPay & " per week."
       End With

   End Sub
   ```
6. The book graciously says:

The procedure declares an object `Employee` as a new instance of `clsEmployee`. It then assigns values to the four properties of the object and generates a message box displaying the employee name and weekly pay. The object’s method, `EmpWeeklyPay`, is
used to generate the displayed pay.

### I'm stuck here people

As far as i know when we put (an original VBA-made and not a custom one from the class module) a property after an object for example
    `Application.Name`
...VBA returns a String value that represents the name of the object. OK, so VBA somehow knows how to do this. But I just cannot understand **how** is it possible in the books paradigm to **create a custom** property *just* by typing with nothing hard-coded

```
Public EmpName As String
Public EmpID As String
Public EmpRate As Double
Public EmpWeeklyHrs As Double
```

...**just as Name property differs from Value property, what creates up there 4 different properties? I mean how are their mechanics are different? What makes property `EmpName` different to `EmpID`???** For all I know they are just variables declared in the class module. How can we create custom object properties just by declaring variables in the class module??? Shouldn't we somehow input the mechanics, a demarcation, the chassis if you will, so when I use/set `EmpID` it will go to look the employees ID and not his name. What is actually assuring me that when I call the `EmpRate` it won't go for the `EmpWeeklyHrs` it's the same data type and there is no other type of code in their "blueprint" the class module to stop things from getting unreliable. There's surely something hardcoded that makes `Value` and `Name` property different how can we only declare variables in the custom made object? it makes no sense to me

**thank you for watching my long long long question**

Comment: Perhaps one thing to realize is the built-in classes like `Application` are (in a functional sense) doing the same thing as your custom class. You would not expect `Application.Name` to be confused with `Application.Intersect`, right? Of course not, and the reason is those properties have different declarations in the `Application` class, just like your `EmpID` and `EmpRate`.

Comment: Nomenclature: In the first block of code, what you are calling Properties are really Variables, and what you're calling a Method is a Property.

Comment: The `Dim Employee As clsEmployee` declares the object variable Employee which will have properties and behaviors defined in the class clsEmployee. Same way as `Dim sLabel As String` declares the variable sLabel with the properties and behaviors defined by the built in class String.  The variable Employee is not instantiated (created) until `Set Employee = New clsEmployee`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you are asking, here is my answer:

First question:

> Dim Employee as clsEmployee 'why is this outside of the code block?

When you do this, you can reference Employee from different parts (subs) of your code. It becomes accessible to the following code. This is optional. You could use the above line only when required by specifying in inside the sub you want. This concept is usualy discussed under the concept of variable reference scope. It is not special to class objects but any variable you use follow the same rule. Take a look at: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141693).

Second question:

> What is actually assuring me that when i call the EmpRate it won't go
>   for the EmpWeeklyHrs it's the same data type and there is no other
>   type of code in their "blueprint" the class module to stop things from
>   getting unreliable.

Compilers and interpreters are very specific about variable names. Naming is fundametal aspect of coding ever since registers were used in Assembler. When you specify Employee.EmpRate, then data in the address assigned to Employee.EmpRate will be used, I see no possibility it could confuse Employee.EmpRate with Employee.EmpWeeklyHrs. The two variables/properties have different names and hence will have 2 distinct storage locations.

Edit to explain with a VERY VERY simplified illustration (this is now what happens of course, but it is meant to illustrate the idea):
[image]
Now, when you code

```
Doc = Employee.EmpName
```

VBA goes to the storage location of the instance called "Employee" and finds that the property called 'Name" is stored with a displacement of 8 chars from the base address of value 1000 of the object. It then goes and assigns the string "Scott" found at location 1008 to the variable Doc.

Comment: I read you answer VERY carefully. Well I don't write Employee.EmpRate in the Class module where you have the 'blueprints' of the custom object. The Employee.EmpRate has been writen in the regular module

Comment: When you create a new object from a class, each property is assigned a distinct memory location. Within a given class, a reference to EmpRate would mean EmpRate of an object, that object is determined at run-time when the class is instntiated (when an object is created from the class).

Comment: i think the intellisense sees it because the Employee is referenced with the clsEmployee (the class module) and these properties are declared and packed in the same class module with the rest of the blueprints. But when i call Name something in VBA "works" behing the scene and brings me the String Value of the name...here in the blueprint all we have is a viariable declaration...nothing more. To me EmpID is just a after the object instance Employee in the Intellisense but it has no way of operating something like RETRIEVING AN ID because all we have in the 'blueprints' is a declared variable

Comment: What do you mean by saying: ...that object is determined at runtime... maybe we have something here

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more

Comment: The blueprint is just a blueprint (think of it maybe as a shopping list of items), it does not hold any specific values before run time, that is before execution (your shopping basket begins to be filled from the shopping list when you are doing the actual shopping) . When you go to run time, and when you create an object of the blue print, memory is allocated based on your blue print specs.

Comment: So when you create the object instance you can use the property and equal her to something which is the data relevant to ID's right? if it is EmpID. That's the hole purpose?

Comment: Well then these properties MUST (as i understand it) always be set in the regular module where we have the instance

Comment: Yes, you can't refer to a property outside the class without an object name. Outside the class, you get an error when you do EmpID=5 you have to create an object such as Employee first and then do Employee.Empid=5. Inside the class code, you can use EmpID=5.

Comment: Yes but before you allocate something on a Property if i type Doc = Employee.Name i will get in string value the employee name. There is something hardcoded that extracts the word Employee as a String value  and puts it where you want to put it. If i type Yok = Employee.EmpID what will i get since the only thing in the bluepring is a variable declaration?

Comment: A property can be referenced using this format: ObjectName.PropertyName. If you have created an object, then the "blueprint" is identified when you create the object from the blueprint. Since the property name within the object is unique, the corresponding value of that property is returned.

Comment: Your patience i great and i thank you but i need to grasp this. On  Doc = Employee.Name the Name employee extracts the word Employee and saves it in a String value named Doc...so there is definitely some functionality involved...in the EmpID the only thing it can be done is to be equaled with something because all we have is a variable declared in the class module

Comment: I will provide a simple chart for you after few minutes

Comment: that will be splendid

Comment: Sir work has spiraled out of control today i will have time to see them very carefully tomorrow and continue out conversation